# Unable to retrieve contentView of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I definitively need help here...

I am creating a custom UITableViewCell programmatically adding subviews to a Cell’s content view.

I followed the example of the tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

First it creates the reusable cell or get the content view if it already exists.
Then it set the picture.

```
#import "NSString+MD5.h"
#import "UIImageView+Network.h"

(....)

#define PHOTO_TAG 1
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    PELOTFriendTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UIImageView *photo;
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Creating cell");
        cell = [[PELOTFriendTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42, 17, 55, 55)];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Reusing cell");
        photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
        NSLog(@"%@",photo);
    }

(....)

    if (friend.pictureUrl==nil) {
        NSLog(@"Setting default photo");
        [photo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-picture.png"]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Setting photo from URL");
        [photo loadImageFromURL:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:friend.pictureUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-picture.png"] cachingKey: [friend.pictureUrl MD5Hash]];
    }
```

The NSLog shows me that

```
photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
```

sometimes returns UITableViewCellContentView* instead of UIImageView* and I get an "unrecognized selector" error.

```
2014-08-15 11:41:27.747 MyApp[79972:60b] <UIImageView: 0xc722840; frame = (60 17; 55 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xc7228c0>>

2014-08-15 11:41:27.750 MyApp[79972:60b] <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xc840c90; frame = (0 0; 338 79.5); tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc8409d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc840b60>>
```

The first one was the image initialized with [photo setImage] and the second one was the image initialized with [photo loadImageFromURL].

It is driving me crazy. 
Any thoughts?

Tks,

## EDIT 1

The first time it renders the table, it works. The problem happens when I call [tableview reloadData] and it calls [cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG]

## EDIT 2

The reproducible code is:

PELOTReproduceBugViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PELOTReproduceBugViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *friendsTableView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *reloadButton;

-(IBAction)reload:(id)sender;

@end
```

PELOTReproduceBugViewController.m

```
#import "PELOTReproduceBugViewController.h"

@implementation PELOTReproduceBugViewController

@synthesize friendsTableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)reload:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"reload!");
    [friendsTableView reloadData];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad!");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    friendsTableView.delegate = self;

    friendsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    friendsTableView.opaque = NO;
    friendsTableView.backgroundView = nil;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)popViewToGetBack:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"** numberOfSectionsInTableView");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"** numberOfRowsInSection");
    return 3;
}

#define PHOTO_TAG 1
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = (int) [indexPath row];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"** 1[%d]",row);

    UIImageView *photo=nil;
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Creating cell");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row;

        photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42, 17, 55, 55)];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];

        NSLog(@"** 2a[%d]: %@",row,photo);
    } else {
        photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
        NSLog(@"** 2b[%d]: %@",row,photo);
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSLog(@"** 3 %d",row);
    [photo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-picture.png"]];

    NSLog(@"** 4");
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}




/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

@end
```

The output is:

```
2014-08-16 17:46:43.432 BugApp[83096:60b] viewDidLoad!
2014-08-16 17:46:43.447 BugApp[83096:60b] ** numberOfSectionsInTableView
2014-08-16 17:46:43.450 BugApp[83096:60b] ** numberOfRowsInSection
2014-08-16 17:46:43.452 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 1[0]
2014-08-16 17:46:43.453 BugApp[83096:60b] Creating cell
2014-08-16 17:46:43.455 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 2a[0]: <UIImageView: 0xc8b23f0; frame = (42 17; 55 55); autoresize = LM+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xc8b2470>>
2014-08-16 17:46:43.456 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 3 0
2014-08-16 17:46:43.459 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 4
2014-08-16 17:46:43.460 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 1[1]
2014-08-16 17:46:43.461 BugApp[83096:60b] Creating cell
2014-08-16 17:46:43.463 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 2a[1]: <UIImageView: 0xc8b5150; frame = (42 17; 55 55); autoresize = LM+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xc8b51d0>>
2014-08-16 17:46:43.464 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 3 1
2014-08-16 17:46:43.465 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 4
2014-08-16 17:46:43.467 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 1[2]
2014-08-16 17:46:43.468 BugApp[83096:60b] Creating cell
2014-08-16 17:46:43.470 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 2a[2]: <UIImageView: 0xc7ef9a0; frame = (42 17; 55 55); autoresize = LM+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xc7eb7a0>>
2014-08-16 17:46:43.471 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 3 2
2014-08-16 17:46:43.472 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 4

2014-08-16 17:46:48.658 BugApp[83096:60b] reload!
2014-08-16 17:46:48.658 BugApp[83096:60b] ** numberOfSectionsInTableView
2014-08-16 17:46:48.659 BugApp[83096:60b] ** numberOfRowsInSection
2014-08-16 17:46:48.660 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 1[0]
2014-08-16 17:46:48.661 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 2b[0]: <UIImageView: 0xc8b23f0; frame = (60 17; 55 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xc8b2470>>
2014-08-16 17:46:48.661 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 3 0
2014-08-16 17:46:48.661 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 4
2014-08-16 17:46:48.662 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 1[1]
2014-08-16 17:46:48.662 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 2b[1]: <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xc8b4df0; frame = (0 0; 338 79.5); tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc8b5100>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc8b4f60>>
2014-08-16 17:46:48.663 BugApp[83096:60b] ** 3 1
2014-08-16 17:46:48.663 BugApp[83096:60b] -[UITableViewCellContentView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc8b4df0
2014-08-16 17:46:48.678 BugApp[83096:60b] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.07 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: -[UITableViewCellContentView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc8b4df0
2014-08-16 17:46:53.684 BugApp[83096:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc8b4df0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x021a11e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f208e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0223e243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0219150b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x021910ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   BugApp                         0x0003387b -[PELOTReproduceBugViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 1083
    6   UIKit                               0x0057e11f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x0057e1f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
```

Note that the first time

```
photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
```

is called, it works. The second, it doesn't.

To reproduce you must call [table reloadData].

Comment: If you initialize your UIImageView *photo as nil, does the problem go away? UIImageView *photo = nil;

Comment: No matter what's the problem here, but this is bad technique. Using the current advocated implementations, you will always get a cell returned, so the initialization will never fire. I strongly suggest to create a subclass (and then just make the image view a property).

Comment: @Eiko, given the OP's implementation, the initialization will fire, though I agree that this isn't the best way to create a custom cell, despite Apple's sample code.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I copied you code, and always got an image view in the log. I agree with Eico that this is not the best way to do this now. It would be better to create the cell's subviews in its init method, and make any subviews properties, so you can refer to them by name, rather than using viewWithTag:. If you do it that way, you should register the class (registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:) in viewDidLoad, and then there's no need to check for a nil cell.

Comment: @Chocksmith I wonder if you've accidentally used assignment instead of comparison somewhere when checking the views tags, the code you've shown doesn't have this problem but the other code might do, check your `if` and `while` conditions at the related files.

Comment: Eiko and @rdelmar, thank you very much for your help! I thought that it was the way recommended by Apple. I am not sure if I understand your recommendation. Do you have any link with a sample code?

Comment: @rdelmar, the first time you run it works because cell will be nil. The problem happens after I call [tableView reloadData] and it call viewWithTag.

Comment: Will - initializing photo with nil does not change the results.

Comment: What's in that PELOTFriendTableViewCell, what's in the prepareForReuse method?

Comment: @eiko nothing. PELOTFriendTableViewCell extends UITableViewCell but does not introduce anything new. (dummy code I did)

Comment: @rdelmar I posted a reproducible code. I am investigating other ways to do it but I am still investigating why it happens. I need to go to the bottom of this. I understand that there are other ways to do it, but if I do not understand why it happens, I cannot sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for viewWithTag includes this sentence: "This method searches the current view and all of its subviews for the specified view."

When you do this: cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row;

When indexPath.row == 1, then the cell.contentView.tag is 1, and it'll be found instead of the image, whose tag is also 1. I think it'll only happen for row 1.